# PostgreSQL: array in text to array

Tags: postgresql

I have JSON array in `text` type field in DB, and I want to check whether there are some elements in the array, and in that case, add some elements to this array and save it back to DB. The main issue I am having is that this text field looks like this:

```
["elem1","elem2","elem3"]
```

and I cannot figure out how to work with those double-quotes.

When I tried `to_json` it resulted in:

```
"[\"elem1\",\"elem2\",\"elem3\"]"
```

When I tried `string_to_array`:

```
{"[\"elem1\"","\"elem2\"","\"elem3\"]"}
```

I just need something like that:

```
['elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a JSON array, simply cast it into `json` directly:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=36c2bb0a2c996efeb0e5b0ef05341110)

```
SELECT '["elem1","elem2","elem3"]'::json
```

If you need a simple array (without JSON), you need to expand the elements of the JSON array (`json_array_elements_text()`) and aggregate them afterwards (`array_agg()`):

```
SELECT 
    array_agg(elems)
FROM mytable,
    json_array_elements_text(mydata::json) AS elems
```